# Bitnami ELK in Azure only showing last event

Tags: elastic-stack, bitnami

I created an ELK vm using the bitnami template in Azure and can send events, but when I goto the discover tab, it's only showing the last event.

Answer (score 0):

What filters are you using? You might be filtering to show just the last event.

Can you confirm that the events are created despite they are not shown in the Discover Tab of Kibana? You can check the logs shown in LogStash for that by browsing to http://YOUR-SERVER-IP/logstash/

Comment: if I browse to server/logstash it just shows some info metadata. I have run logstash from command line and saw events being output. Is there a way to query ES for the number of events through the developer console?